# How to deploy pwa app developed in angular-cli v7 on the top of the existing website?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps, angular-cli-v7

I have developed a PWA app for my existing website using angular CLI v7. I want to deploy it on the top of my existing website. I want the existing website for desktop users, but for mobile users, it should open the PWA app.

How can I achieve this without any URL redirection?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible without url redirection. PWAs are similar to native apps but are deployed and accessible from **web servers via URLs**, so we don’t need to go through app stores. Whenever a new build of the app is deployed, the service worker treats that build as a new version of the app. You can check this [site](https://itnext.io/build-a-production-ready-pwa-with-angular-and-firebase-8f2a69824fcc) for more details.